# python: Changing the content of a frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I started a project where I want to script an application for my company to capture values of an iterative signal processing job. 
I want to include the option to switch between different modules that require different parameters to test.

When I click on the buttons on the left I want the content of the data entry frame to change to a different set of `Labels` and `Entry` widgets. I tried to put the widgets for 'AAA' in a different class but I don't know how to initialize the class via button click so the widgets in the class get created/visible. I tried it with `.lift()` but that's ugly. I also want to keep the same 2 frames under the data entry frame, and the `ScrolledText` on the right, just working with the active module. Any ideas? Someone can push me in the right direction?

Oh yeah, and this is my first project apart from simple read->replace string-> scripts.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter as tk
import json
import tkFileDialog
import sys
import ScrolledText
from Tkinter import*


class testlogger(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        menubar = tk.Menu(self)

        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="New")
        filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.load_file)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=self.safe_file)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save as...")
        filemenu.add_command(label="Close")
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

        editmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        editmenu.add_command(label="Undo")
        editmenu.add_separator()
        editmenu.add_command(label="Cut")
        editmenu.add_command(label="Copy")
        editmenu.add_command(label="Paste")
        editmenu.add_command(label="Delete")
        editmenu.add_command(label="Select All")
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)

        helpmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        helpmenu.add_command(label="Help Index")
        helpmenu.add_command(label="About...")
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

        self.config(menu=menubar)

        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        treeFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        treeFrame.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='NW')

        b1 = Button(treeFrame, text=u'AAA', command=self.AAAlift)
        b1.pack(fill='x')

        b2 = Button(treeFrame, text=u'RADON', command=self.radonlift)
        b2.pack(fill='x')

        b3 = Button(treeFrame, text=u'Adaptive Subtract')
        b3.pack(fill='x')

        b4 = Button(treeFrame, text=u'GMP')
        b4.pack(fill='x')

        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        #
        #   
        #
        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.enterData = tk.LabelFrame(self, text=" Data Entry ")
        self.enterData.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=4, sticky='NW', \
                padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

        titleAAA = tk.Label(self.enterData, text="AAA")
        titleAAA.grid(row=1, columnspan=4, sticky='N', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.freqInput = tk.StringVar()
        self.freqInput2 = tk.StringVar()    
        self.thresInput = tk.StringVar()
        self.widthInput = tk.StringVar()

        self.minFreq = tk.Label(self.enterData, text="Minimum Frequency")
        self.minFreq.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        minFreqData = tk.Entry(self.enterData, textvariable=self.freqInput)
        minFreqData.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.maxFreq = tk.Label(self.enterData, text="Maximum Frequency")
        self.maxFreq.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        maxFreqData = tk.Entry(self.enterData, textvariable=self.freqInput2)
        maxFreqData.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.threshold = tk.Label(self.enterData, text="Threshold")
        self.threshold.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        thresData = tk.Entry(self.enterData, textvariable=self.thresInput)
        thresData.grid(row=2, column=4, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.width = tk.Label(self.enterData, text="SpatialWidth")
        self.width.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        widthData = tk.Entry(self.enterData, textvariable=self.widthInput)
        widthData.grid(row=3, column=4, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.valueList = [self.freqInput, self.freqInput2, self.thresInput, self.widthInput]
        self.labelList = [self.minFreq, self.maxFreq, self.threshold, self.width]

        enteredAAAData = []

        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

        self.radon = LabelFrame(self, text=" Data Entry ")
        self.radon.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=4, sticky='NW', \
                padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

        titleRadon = Label(self.radon, text="Radon Fwd Transform")
        titleRadon.grid(row=1, columnspan=4, sticky='N', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.minMOInput = StringVar()
        self.maxMOInput = StringVar()    
        self.offsetInput = StringVar()
        self.numpInput = StringVar()
        self.motypeInput = StringVar()
        self.maxfreqInput = StringVar()

        self.minMO = Label(self.radon, text="Minimum Moveout")
        self.minMO.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        minMOData = Entry(self.radon, textvariable=self.minMOInput)
        minMOData.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.maxMO = Label(self.radon, text="Maximum Moveout")
        self.maxFreq.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        maxMOData = Entry(self.radon, textvariable=self.maxMOInput)
        maxMOData.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.offset = Label(self.radon, text="Reference Offset")
        self.offset.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        offsetData = Entry(self.radon, textvariable=self.offsetInput)
        offsetData.grid(row=2, column=4, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.numP = Label(self.radon, text="Number of P-Traces")
        self.numP.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        numPData = Entry(self.radon, textvariable=self.numpInput)
        numPData.grid(row=3, column=4, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.motype = Label(self.radon, text="Moveout Type")
        self.motype.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        motypeData = Entry(self.radon, textvariable=self.motypeInput)
        motypeData.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.maxfreq = Label(self.radon, text="Maximum Frequency")
        self.maxfreq.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        maxfreqData = Entry(self.radon, textvariable=self.maxfreqInput)
        maxfreqData.grid(row=4, column=4, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.valueList = [self.minMOInput, self.maxMOInput, self.offsetInput, self.numpInput, self.motypeInput, self.maxfreqInput]
        self.labelList = [self.minMO, self.maxMO, self.offset, self.numP, self.motype, self.maxfreq]

        enteredRadonData = []

        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   

        evalData = tk.Frame(self)
        evalData.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky='NW', \
                padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

        evalLabel = tk.Label(evalData, text="Evaluation")
        evalLabel.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky='N', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.eval_state = tk.StringVar()

        goodRadio = tk.Radiobutton(evalData, text="Good", variable=self.eval_state, value='Good')
        goodRadio.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

        badRadio = tk.Radiobutton(evalData, text="Bad", variable=self.eval_state, value='Bad')
        badRadio.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

        sameRadio = tk.Radiobutton(evalData, text="Same", variable=self.eval_state, value='Same')
        sameRadio.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

        qcDisp = tk.Label(evalData, text="QC Displays:")
        qcDisp.grid(row=2,column=4, sticky='W', padx=10, pady=2)

        self.checkB4 = tk.IntVar()

        optionBefore = tk.Checkbutton(evalData, text="Before", variable=self.checkB4, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        optionBefore.grid(row=1, column=5, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

        optionAfter = tk.Checkbutton(evalData, text="After", onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        optionAfter.grid(row=2, column=5, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

        optionDiff = tk.Checkbutton(evalData, text="Difference", onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        optionDiff.grid(row=3, column=5, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

        optionSpectrum = tk.Checkbutton(evalData, text="Frequency Spectrum", onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        optionSpectrum.grid(row=1, column=6, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

        optionAuto = tk.Checkbutton(evalData, text="Auto Correlation", onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        optionAuto.grid(row=2, column=6, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

        optionBanana = tk.Checkbutton(evalData, text="I'm a Banana", onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        optionBanana.grid(row=3, column=6, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        self.comment = tk.Text(self, height=5, bg='white')
        self.comment.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky='NW', \
                padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

        submit_b = tk.Button(self, text=u"Submit", command=self.enter_data)
        submit_b.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky='NE')

        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        protocolFrame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Protocol")
        protocolFrame.grid(row=1, column=2, rowspan=3, sticky='NW')

        self.protocolText = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(protocolFrame,state='disabled',height=30, width=70)
        self.protocolText.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='NE')

        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        self.L = []


    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     

    def enter_data(self):


        x = self.labelList[0].cget('text')
        y = self.valueList[0].get()
        self.L.append(x + ': ' + y)

        x = self.labelList[1].cget('text')
        y = self.valueList[1].get()
        self.L.append(x + ': ' + y)

        x = self.labelList[2].cget('text')
        y = self.valueList[2].get()
        self.L.append(x + ': ' + y)

        x = self.labelList[3].cget('text')
        y = self.valueList[3].get()
        self.L.append(x + ': ' + y)


        x = self.eval_state.get()
        self.L.append(x)

        if self.checkB4 == 1: 
            y = self.optionBefore.cget('text')
            self.L.append(y)

        x = self.comment.get('1.0','end')
        self.L.append(x)
        self.L.append('-------------------------------------\n')

        self.protocolText.config(state='normal')
        self.protocolText.insert(tk.END, '\n'.join(self.L))
        self.protocolText.config(state='disabled')

        self.L = []

    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def safe_file(self):
        s = self.protocolText.get('1.0','end')
        with open('my_json', 'w') as fp:
              json.dump(s, fp)

    def load_file(self):

        options = {}
        options['defaultextension'] = '.txt'
        options['filetypes'] = [('all files', '.*'), ('text files', '.txt')]
        options['initialdir'] = '/home'
        options['parent'] = self.parent
        options['title'] = "Open a file"
        self.protocolText.config(state='normal')
        with tkFileDialog.askopenfile(mode='r', **options) as f_handle:
            for line in f_handle:
                self.protocolText.insert(tk.END, f_handle)
        self.protocolText.config(state='disabled')

    def AAAlift(self):
        self.enterData.lift()

    def radonlift(self):
        self.radon.lift()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = testlogger(None)
    app.title('Testlogger')
    app.mainloop()
```

When app starts:

[image]

When AAA is pressed:

[image]

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect, making it hard for us to know which code belongs to which function or class.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code slightly. Basically I added containerFrame, to wrap the LabelFrames. I think its easier to make it easer this way. I also added some padding in other places to make the Protocol part inline with others.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter as tk
import json
import tkFileDialog
import sys
import ScrolledText
from Tkinter import*


class testlogger(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        menubar = tk.Menu(self)

        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="New")
        filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.load_file)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=self.safe_file)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save as...")
        filemenu.add_command(label="Close")
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

        editmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        editmenu.add_command(label="Undo")
        editmenu.add_separator()
        editmenu.add_command(label="Cut")
        editmenu.add_command(label="Copy")
        editmenu.add_command(label="Paste")
        editmenu.add_command(label="Delete")
        editmenu.add_command(label="Select All")
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)

        helpmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        helpmenu.add_command(label="Help Index")
        helpmenu.add_command(label="About...")
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

        self.config(menu=menubar)

        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        treeFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        treeFrame.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='NW')

        b1 = Button(treeFrame, text=u'AAA', command=self.AAAlift)
        b1.pack(fill='x')

        b2 = Button(treeFrame, text=u'RADON', command=self.radonlift)
        b2.pack(fill='x')

        b3 = Button(treeFrame, text=u'Adaptive Subtract')
        b3.pack(fill='x')

        b4 = Button(treeFrame, text=u'GMP')
        b4.pack(fill='x')

        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        #
        #   
        #
        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        self.containerFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.containerFrame.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=4, sticky='NW', \
                                        padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=1, ipady=1)

        self.enterData = tk.LabelFrame(self.containerFrame, text=" Data Entry ")
        #self.enterData.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)        
        self.enterData.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='NW', ipadx=17)

#         self.enterData.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=4, sticky='NW', \
#                 padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

        titleAAA = tk.Label(self.enterData, text="AAA")
        titleAAA.grid(row=1, columnspan=4, sticky='N', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.freqInput = tk.StringVar()
        self.freqInput2 = tk.StringVar()    
        self.thresInput = tk.StringVar()
        self.widthInput = tk.StringVar()

        self.minFreq = tk.Label(self.enterData, text="Minimum Frequency")
        self.minFreq.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        minFreqData = tk.Entry(self.enterData, textvariable=self.freqInput)
        minFreqData.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.maxFreq = tk.Label(self.enterData, text="Maximum Frequency")
        self.maxFreq.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        maxFreqData = tk.Entry(self.enterData, textvariable=self.freqInput2)
        maxFreqData.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.threshold = tk.Label(self.enterData, text="Threshold")
        self.threshold.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        thresData = tk.Entry(self.enterData, textvariable=self.thresInput)
        thresData.grid(row=2, column=4, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.width = tk.Label(self.enterData, text="SpatialWidth")
        self.width.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        widthData = tk.Entry(self.enterData, textvariable=self.widthInput)
        widthData.grid(row=3, column=4, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.valueList = [self.freqInput, self.freqInput2, self.thresInput, self.widthInput]
        self.labelList = [self.minFreq, self.maxFreq, self.threshold, self.width]

        enteredAAAData = []

        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 



        self.radon = LabelFrame(self.containerFrame, text=" Data Entry ")
        #self.radon.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.radon.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='NW', ipadx=0)       

        titleRadon = Label(self.radon, text="Radon Fwd Transform")
        titleRadon.grid(row=1, columnspan=4, sticky='N', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.minMOInput = StringVar()
        self.maxMOInput = StringVar()    
        self.offsetInput = StringVar()
        self.numpInput = StringVar()
        self.motypeInput = StringVar()
        self.maxfreqInput = StringVar()

        self.minMO = Label(self.radon, text="Minimum Moveout")
        self.minMO.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        minMOData = Entry(self.radon, textvariable=self.minMOInput)
        minMOData.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.maxMO = Label(self.radon, text="Maximum Moveout")
        self.maxFreq.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        maxMOData = Entry(self.radon, textvariable=self.maxMOInput)
        maxMOData.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.offset = Label(self.radon, text="Reference Offset")
        self.offset.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        offsetData = Entry(self.radon, textvariable=self.offsetInput)
        offsetData.grid(row=2, column=4, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.numP = Label(self.radon, text="Number of P-Traces")
        self.numP.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        numPData = Entry(self.radon, textvariable=self.numpInput)
        numPData.grid(row=3, column=4, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.motype = Label(self.radon, text="Moveout Type")
        self.motype.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        motypeData = Entry(self.radon, textvariable=self.motypeInput)
        motypeData.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.maxfreq = Label(self.radon, text="Maximum Frequency")
        self.maxfreq.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        maxfreqData = Entry(self.radon, textvariable=self.maxfreqInput)
        maxfreqData.grid(row=4, column=4, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.valueList = [self.minMOInput, self.maxMOInput, self.offsetInput, self.numpInput, self.motypeInput, self.maxfreqInput]
        self.labelList = [self.minMO, self.maxMO, self.offset, self.numP, self.motype, self.maxfreq]

        enteredRadonData = []

        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   

        evalData = tk.Frame(self)
        evalData.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky='NW', \
                padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

        evalLabel = tk.Label(evalData, text="Evaluation")
        evalLabel.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky='N', padx=5, pady=2)

        self.eval_state = tk.StringVar()

        goodRadio = tk.Radiobutton(evalData, text="Good", variable=self.eval_state, value='Good')
        goodRadio.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

        badRadio = tk.Radiobutton(evalData, text="Bad", variable=self.eval_state, value='Bad')
        badRadio.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

        sameRadio = tk.Radiobutton(evalData, text="Same", variable=self.eval_state, value='Same')
        sameRadio.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

        qcDisp = tk.Label(evalData, text="QC Displays:")
        qcDisp.grid(row=2,column=4, sticky='W', padx=10, pady=2)

        self.checkB4 = tk.IntVar()

        optionBefore = tk.Checkbutton(evalData, text="Before", variable=self.checkB4, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        optionBefore.grid(row=1, column=5, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

        optionAfter = tk.Checkbutton(evalData, text="After", onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        optionAfter.grid(row=2, column=5, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

        optionDiff = tk.Checkbutton(evalData, text="Difference", onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        optionDiff.grid(row=3, column=5, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

        optionSpectrum = tk.Checkbutton(evalData, text="Frequency Spectrum", onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        optionSpectrum.grid(row=1, column=6, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

        optionAuto = tk.Checkbutton(evalData, text="Auto Correlation", onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        optionAuto.grid(row=2, column=6, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

        optionBanana = tk.Checkbutton(evalData, text="I'm a Banana", onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        optionBanana.grid(row=3, column=6, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        self.comment = tk.Text(self, height=5, bg='white')
        self.comment.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky='NW', \
                          padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

        submit_b = tk.Button(self, text=u"Submit", command=self.enter_data)
        submit_b.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky='NE')

        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        protocolFrame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Protocol")
        protocolFrame.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=45, pady=5, rowspan=3, sticky='NW')

        self.protocolText = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(protocolFrame,state='disabled',height=30, width=70)
        self.protocolText.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='NE')

        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        self.L = []


    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     

    def enter_data(self):


        x = self.labelList[0].cget('text')
        y = self.valueList[0].get()
        self.L.append(x + ': ' + y)

        x = self.labelList[1].cget('text')
        y = self.valueList[1].get()
        self.L.append(x + ': ' + y)

        x = self.labelList[2].cget('text')
        y = self.valueList[2].get()
        self.L.append(x + ': ' + y)

        x = self.labelList[3].cget('text')
        y = self.valueList[3].get()
        self.L.append(x + ': ' + y)


        x = self.eval_state.get()
        self.L.append(x)

        if self.checkB4 == 1: 
            y = self.optionBefore.cget('text')
            self.L.append(y)

        x = self.comment.get('1.0','end')
        self.L.append(x)
        self.L.append('-------------------------------------\n')

        self.protocolText.config(state='normal')
        self.protocolText.insert(tk.END, '\n'.join(self.L))
        self.protocolText.config(state='disabled')

        self.L = []

    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def safe_file(self):
        s = self.protocolText.get('1.0','end')
        with open('my_json', 'w') as fp:
              json.dump(s, fp)

    def load_file(self):

        options = {}
        options['defaultextension'] = '.txt'
        options['filetypes'] = [('all files', '.*'), ('text files', '.txt')]
        options['initialdir'] = '/home'
        options['parent'] = self.parent
        options['title'] = "Open a file"
        self.protocolText.config(state='normal')
        with tkFileDialog.askopenfile(mode='r', **options) as f_handle:
            for line in f_handle:
                self.protocolText.insert(tk.END, f_handle)
        self.protocolText.config(state='disabled')

    def AAAlift(self):
        #self.enterData.grid_forget()
        self.radon.grid_remove() 
        self.enterData.grid()

    def radonlift(self):
        self.enterData.grid_remove() 
        self.radon.grid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = testlogger(None)
    app.title('Testlogger')
    app.mainloop()
```

The screenshots are:

[image]
[image]

Obviously more work is needed to make everything "even" and inline with each other, but pressing AAA and RADON buttons works as expected (I think). You can expand/amend on my modifications, and hopefully it will allow you to achieve desired effect.